# while calling an error is coming like Use of undeclared type 'district'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
struct District {
    var district:[String]=["districtName","headQuarters"]
}

var telangana:[district] = ["rangareddy","shamshabad","suryapet","suryapet"]
print(telangana)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do and what you have already tried. Please consider adding more details to your post

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics about programming in swift, maybe start with [this online book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to create `struct District` with `districtName` and `headQuarter` as its properties,

```
struct District {
    let districtName: String
    let headQuarter: String
}
```

Now, you can create an `array` of `District` like so,

```
let telangana: [District] = [District(districtName: "rangareddy", headQuarter: "shamshabad"), District(districtName: "suryapet", headQuarter: "suryapet")]
print(telangana)
```

Comment: tq so much for ur support , I just started learning swift from one week

Comment: Sure. Do accept(tick on left) if the answer worked. Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Your struct name is "District" so it should be:

```
var telangana:[District] = ["rangareddy","shamshabad","suryapet","suryapet"]
```

Although this will not compile because an array or Districts cannot be initialised with [String]

You should try something like:

```
let district1 = District(district:[""rangareddy","shamshabad","suryapet","suryapet""])
var telangana:[District] = [district1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create first property in your struct

```
struct District {
    var districtName: String
    var headQuarters: String
}
```

then create array of struct

```
var telangana: [District] = []

telangana.append(District(districtName: "rangareddy", headQuarters: "shamshabad"))
print(telangana)
```

Comment: This will not compile.